# .not(this) is not working on click. I'm not using a list

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to toggle a class `.dica-item` to `.dica-item.active` on click. This works fine. However I can not remove the class when another item is clicked. I've seen examples that work fine before however this is a situation where someone is using a list and siblings. Is there anyway to do the same thing here?

```
<div id="slider-items" class="et_pb_module dica_divi_carousel dica_divi_carousel_0">
    <div class="et_pb_module_inner">
        <div class="dica-container  arrow-show-hover arrow-outer-position" data-desktop="6" data-tablet="3" data-mobile="3" data-speed="250" data-arrow="on" data-dots="off" data-autoplay="off" data-autospeed="1000" data-loop="off" item-spacing="30" center-mode="off" slider-effec="1" cover-rotate="50" pause-onhover="off" data-multislide="off" data-cfshadow="on" data-order="0" data-lazyload="off" data-lazybefore="off" data-scroller_effect="off" data-autowidth="off" data-item_spacing_tablet="30" data-item_spacing_phone="30">
            <div class="swiper-container swiper-container-initialized swiper-container-horizontal">
                <div class="swiper-wrapper" style="width: 1878.33px; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); transition-duration: 0ms;"><div class="et_pb_module dica_divi_carouselitem dica_divi_carouselitem_0 et_clickable swiper-slide-visible swiper-slide-active" style="width: 238.333px; margin-right: 30px;">
            <div class="et_pb_module_inner">
                <div class="dica-item active">
                    <div class="dica-image-container"><a class="image" href="#aerospace" data-et-has-event-already="true"><img src="http://meilink.is-een-geweldige-klant.nl/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/Naamloos-1.jpg" alt="" class="dica-item-image"></a></div>
                            <div class="dica-item-content">
                                <h4><a href="#aerospace" data-et-has-event-already="true">Aerospace</a></h4>
                                <div class="content"></div>
                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
            </div>
        </div><div class="et_pb_module dica_divi_carouselitem dica_divi_carouselitem_1 et_clickable swiper-slide-visible swiper-slide-next" style="width: 238.333px; margin-right: 30px;">
            
            
            
            
            <div class="et_pb_module_inner">
                <div class="dica-item active">
                                <div class="dica-image-container"><a class="image" href="#automotive" data-et-has-event-already="true"><img src="http://meilink.is-een-geweldige-klant.nl/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/Naamloos-1.jpg" alt="" class="dica-item-image"></a></div>
                            <div class="dica-item-content">
                                <h4><a href="#automotive" data-et-has-event-already="true">Automotive</a></h4>
                                <div class="content"></div>
                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
            </div>
        </div><div class="et_pb_module dica_divi_carouselitem dica_divi_carouselitem_2 et_clickable swiper-slide-visible" style="width: 238.333px; margin-right: 30px;">
            
            
            
            
            <div class="et_pb_module_inner">
                <div class="dica-item active">
                                <div class="dica-image-container"><a class="image" href="#aerospace" data-et-has-event-already="true"><img src="http://meilink.is-een-geweldige-klant.nl/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/Naamloos-1.jpg" alt="" class="dica-item-image"></a></div>
                            <div class="dica-item-content">
                                <h4><a href="#aerospace" data-et-has-event-already="true">Aerospace</a></h4>
                                <div class="content"></div>
                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
            </div>
        </div><div class="et_pb_module dica_divi_carouselitem dica_divi_carouselitem_3 et_clickable swiper-slide-visible" style="width: 238.333px; margin-right: 30px;">
            
            
            
            
            <div class="et_pb_module_inner">
                <div class="dica-item">
                                <div class="dica-image-container"><a class="image" href="#agrodairy" data-et-has-event-already="true"><img src="http://meilink.is-een-geweldige-klant.nl/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/Naamloos-1.jpg" alt="" class="dica-item-image"></a></div>
                            <div class="dica-item-content">
                                <h4><a href="#agrodairy" data-et-has-event-already="true">Agro &amp; Dairy</a></h4>
                                <div class="content"></div>
                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
            </div>
        </div><div class="et_pb_module dica_divi_carouselitem dica_divi_carouselitem_4 et_clickable swiper-slide-visible" style="width: 238.333px; margin-right: 30px;">
            
            
            
            
            <div class="et_pb_module_inner">
                <div class="dica-item active">
                                <div class="dica-image-container"><a class="image" href="#defensie" data-et-has-event-already="true"><img src="http://meilink.is-een-geweldige-klant.nl/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/Naamloos-1.jpg" alt="" class="dica-item-image"></a></div>
                            <div class="dica-item-content">
                                <h4><a href="#defensie" data-et-has-event-already="true">Defensie</a></h4>
                                <div class="content"></div>
                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
            </div>
        </div><div class="et_pb_module dica_divi_carouselitem dica_divi_carouselitem_5 et_clickable swiper-slide-visible" style="width: 238.333px; margin-right: 30px;">
            
            
            
            
            <div class="et_pb_module_inner">
                <div class="dica-item">
                                <div class="dica-image-container"><a class="image" href="#sectorx" data-et-has-event-already="true"><img src="http://meilink.is-een-geweldige-klant.nl/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/Naamloos-1.jpg" alt="" class="dica-item-image"></a></div>
                            <div class="dica-item-content">
                                <h4><a href="#sectorx" data-et-has-event-already="true">Sector X</a></h4>
                                <div class="content"></div>
                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
            </div>
        </div><div class="et_pb_module dica_divi_carouselitem dica_divi_carouselitem_6 et_clickable" style="width: 238.333px; margin-right: 30px;">
            
            
            
            
            <div class="et_pb_module_inner">
                <div class="dica-item">
                                <div class="dica-image-container"><a class="image" href="#sectory" data-et-has-event-already="true"><img src="http://meilink.is-een-geweldige-klant.nl/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/Naamloos-1.jpg" alt="" class="dica-item-image"></a></div>
                            <div class="dica-item-content">
                                <h4><a href="#sectory" data-et-has-event-already="true">Sector Y</a></h4>
                                <div class="content"></div>
                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
            </div>
        </div></div>    
                            <span class="swiper-notification" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true"></span></div>    
                            <div class="swiper-button-next dica-next-btn-0" data-icon="5" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-label="Next slide" aria-disabled="false"></div><div class="swiper-button-prev dica-prev-btn-0 swiper-button-disabled" data-icon="4" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-label="Previous slide" aria-disabled="true"></div>
                                                    
                        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I've wrote this piece of jQuery. However now I'm a bit stuck:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {  
    jQuery('.dica-item').click(function(){
         jQuery(this).toggleClass('active').not(this).removeClass('active');
    });  
});
```

Comment: `jQuery(this).not(this)` equals to empty set.

Comment: Use: `jQuery('.dica-item').removeClass('active'); jQuery(this).toggleClass('active')`